# MySQL - JOIN - find the max value in another table and display customer name from first table

Tags: mysql, database, join

```
select discount.RATE, customer.NAME 
from APP.DISCOUNT_CODE as discount 
LEFT JOIN APP.CUSTOMER as customer 
ON discount.DISCOUNT_CODE = customer.DISCOUNT_CODE;
```

When i use this query i get all the discount rate and customer name, but i want to display only one customer who has max discount.RATE..

I tried this query..

```
select max(discount.RATE), customer.NAME 
from APP.DISCOUNT_CODE as discount 
LEFT JOIN APP.CUSTOMER as customer 
ON discount.DISCOUNT_CODE = customer.DISCOUNT_CODE;
```

But i get an error..how to solve this..

This is the table from first query..

[image]

Error is get is running second query using max(discount.RATE) ,

```
[Exception, Error code 30,000, SQLState 42Y35] Column reference 'CUSTOMER.NAME' is invalid. When the SELECT list contains at least one aggregate then all entries must be valid aggregate expressions.
```

Comment: What is the error you are receiving? Also, it may be of some help if you could edit your question to include your table layouts and some sample data from each table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT
    discount.RATE, customer.NAME
    FROM
        APP.DISCOUNT_CODE as discount
        JOIN APP.CUSTOMER as customer ON discount.DISCOUNT_CODE = customer.DISCOUNT_CODE
    ORDER BY
        discount.RATE DESC
    LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

First: you have to write `GROUP BY` in your second query:

```
SELECT max(discount.RATE) AS MAX_DISC_RATE
    ,customer.NAME
FROM APP.DISCOUNT_CODE AS discount
LEFT JOIN APP.CUSTOMER AS customer ON discount.DISCOUNT_CODE = customer.DISCOUNT_CODE
GROUP BY customer.NAME;
```